# How to find out if a computer can accept higher memory capacities in various slot configs?

Tags: memory, motherboard

I'm curious about memory per slot configuration on systems. I've never found clear answers, just some seeming speculative forum posts, but nothing entirely clear about this.  I'll use an example to illustrate:

I have a workstation with an Intel Q77 (HP 8300 Elite CMT) that has 4 slots. This system has a max memory allowance of 32 GB. Crucial.com, for example, says it can take a maximum of 4 x 8 GB DIMMS (for the obvious total of 32 GB).

I have found that memory prices sometimes are more cost effective for 2 x 16 GB DIMMS vs 4 x 8 GB DIMMS.  I therefore may want to upgrade via the more cost effective path.  It seems that one *MIGHT perhaps* lose a little speed by having 2 DIMMS instead (one in 2 slots vs using all 4 slots, but using two diff channels should ameliorate that, no?).

**How can one determine definitively if 2 16 GB DIMMS will work on a motherboard if you cannot find the specifications clearly delineated anywhere?**

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question as asked, usually, one would check the manual. They often have a matrix diagram. The [service manual](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c03612798) for yours does not.

Assuming the manual I linked is the correct one for your system, then the manual is pretty vague. It lists, in two places, part numbers for HP memory (p.82). They only list 8, 4, and 2GB parts.

Sixteen would have been available in 2012, so we might take this to mean they do not support higher capacity dimms.

Further, there is a paragraph which refers to max memory in dual channel mode being 16.

> To achieve the maximum memory support, you can populate the system
>   board  with up to 16-GB of memory configured in a high-performing dual
>   channel mode.

I find this really vague but one could take this to mean "max of 16 in a dual-channel configuration *per two-socket channel*". What you saw at *Crucial* seems to support this interpretation.

Comment: Hmm, yes, this is what I was coming up with, but I was hoping that there were better resources for such situations as I hit it rather frequently with clients. I couldn't even find any info from Intel on this topic for the Q77... :(  Hard to just keep DIMMS of this caliber "laying around" for testing.

Answer (score 0):

On your specifications page I found this:

"**1600-MHz non-ECC DDR3 SDRAM; (4) DIMM slots enabling up to 32GB"**

https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-compaq-elite-8300-convertible-minitower-pc/5232845/document/c03345460